# Author name on main page not showing up

Tags: php, css, wordpress

On my main page, I have posts that underneath have the author name. Or well, should. However nothing actually appears and I'm not sure why they aren't showing. On my `sidebar.php` they do show up. I've tried to see if there was actually something appearing and not being hidden by CSS, however nothing appears at ALL from the `get_the_author()` on the front-page

Heres my front page code:

```
$result = wp_get_recent_posts(array(
    'numberposts' => 1,
    'category' => '',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
));

foreach( $result as $p ){
    ?>
    <!-- The card itself-->
    <div class="card cardcustom">
        <!-- The image -->
        <a href="<?php echo get_permalink($p['ID']) ?>" class="stretched-link"><img class="card-img tinted" src="<?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail_url($p['ID'], array(1438, 500)); ?>" style="height: 500px; object-fit: cover; border-radius: 0px;"/></a>
        <!-- Text over the image -->
        <div class="card-img-overlay card-content">
            <p href="#" class="card-text the-badge badge badge-primary"><?php
            foreach(get_the_category($p['ID']) as $category) {
                echo $category->name . ' ';
            }
            ?></p><br>
            <p class="posttitle card-text" style="font-weight: 600; font-size: 16px;">
            <?php echo $p['post_title']?></p><br />

            <?php
            $authorname = get_the_author();

            echo '<p class="authortext card-text">From ' . '<strong class="colorauthor">' . $authorname . '</strong>' . '</p>';
            ?>
        </div>
    </div>
    <?php
}
?>
```

And here is the code on my sidebar:

```
$result = wp_get_recent_posts(array(
    'numberposts' => 8,
    'category' => '',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
));

foreach( $result as $p ){
    ?>
    <!-- The card itself-->
    <div class="card cardcustom">
        <!-- The image -->
        <a href="<?php echo get_permalink($p['ID']) ?>" class="stretched-link"><img class="card-img tinted" src="<?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail_url($p['ID'], array(440, 240)); ?>" style="border-radius: 0px;"/></a>
        <!-- Text over the image -->
        <div class="card-img-overlay card-content">
            <p href="#" class="card-text the-badge badge badge-primary" style="border-radius: 0px;"><?php
            foreach(get_the_category($p['ID']) as $category) {
                echo $category->name . ' ';
            }
            ?></p><br>
            <p class="posttitle card-text" style="font-weight: 600; font-size: 16px;">
            <?php echo $p['post_title']?></p><br />

            <?php
            $authorname = get_the_author();

            echo '<p class="authortext card-text">From ' . '<strong class="colorauthor">' . $authorname . '</strong>' . '</p>';

            ?>
        </div>
    </div>
<?php
}
?>
```

They're almost identical but for whatever reason it refuses to show up on the main page. You can see what I mean from the screenshots below:

MAIN PAGE:
https://gyazo.com/947f49090fd90a4068725a3968e1e205

SIDEBAR ON A DIFFERENT PAGE:
https://gyazo.com/b9325be19f388dc2d64ae2fe502e3ba4

Comment: I'll suggest the obvious answer because you haven't ruled it out here - the text is actually there but not visible because the CSS isn't working there? Use your browser devtools and inspect the card - is the author name there but invisible?

Comment: Its not there, its completely missing: https://gyazo.com/b2627c828351f79d2ca5502e9d0e59fa

Answer (score 0):

[`get_the_author()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_author/) uses the global `$authordata`.
And [`wp_get_recent_posts()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_recent_posts/) doesn't alter the main query (because it uses [`get_posts()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_posts/) under the hood).

I guess on that sidebar it loads the author of the current page. To verify create another page with another user and try to see if the author changes.

I would suggest you get the author name by `get_the_author_meta('display_name', $p->post_author);` (replace [`get_the_author_meta`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_author_meta/) with `the_author_meta` for simply displaying it).